# How to find lines with 3 sets of double letters (the sets may or may not contain the same letters)

Tags: regex, linux

So I have been doing this for my homework and been on this for hours, ripping my hair out.  I feel like this should not be hard but I cannot get a solution to work.

So far I have this

```
egrep '(.)\1{3}' fileName
```

The problem here is that it can just only find just that specific character I realized.  So it ends up being aa aa aa instead of it being random for all 3 like aa or dd or ee and the line just needs 3 of these.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: First glance, it seems not to match `aa aa aa` but `aaaa`, although not being sure even if current syntax is acceptable by egrep. So to match *random characters* you only need `(.){4}` or `.{4}` or `....`!

Comment: Is it really?  When I do '(.)\1{1}' it finds all the different repeated letters but I just want lines with a set of 3 of them.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right path using back reference.  The problem is `\1` is only ever going to match the first group.  Basically you're matching a single-character group, followed by that character three times.  So `aaaa` will match that regex.

You need three groups.

`(.)\1.*(.)\2.*(.)\3`

Comment: Hmm so I was getting aaaa like the other person commented.  Although this make sense this does not seem to work either?

Comment: I am realizing this won't work because it would look for doubles immediately right after, I would need to find doubles in a sentence.  Is there regex command that would like look at each part?  Like an and operator instead of or (.)\1|(.)\2|(.)\3  except this would be and instead of or

Comment: I modified the regex so it'll also blow through any extra garbage in the line.  Just had to some `.*` in there.

Comment: Oh wow.  It works.  Thank you so much!  So I am guessing the .* is like a way to tell the program to search for these things in other spots instead of immediately after?

Comment: Thank you.  I needed the .* and back references for my other parts of my homework that I am now able to complete.  This was really helpful.